# How to calculate price and quantity with tax in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, calculator

My price: 20

Quantity: 2

Tax: 10%

How to calculate this?

I dont know the formula to do this calculation.

Comment: Hello there, did you try looking up the formula to do this calculation? Simple Google/wikiHow search? Yes? No?

Comment: Yes... @JohnLaw

Comment: I cant get. help me

Answer (score 6):

In your case:

```
var priceWithTax = 20 * 1.10 * 2;
```

or more general:

```
var priceWithTax = price * (1 + taxPercentage / 100) * amount;
```

The order of factors doesn't matter.

Comment: Why that 1 + taxpercentage? is one necessary?

Comment: @user9988550 because to adding `10%` to a value is to get `110%` of this value thus multiplying it by `1.10`

Comment: You'll want to be careful about integer division: If taxPercentage is less than 100, integer division might turn taxPercentage/100 to zero.  Better to use floating point division: 1.0 + taxPercentage/100.0

Comment: @duffymo As far as I know there is no discarding of the decimal places in JavaScript. Do you have some more information on that?

Comment: You are correct - floating point division is the default.  My mistake: https://nickthecoder.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/integer-division-in-javascript/

Answer (score 3):

Just multiply all of them together:

```
const price = 20;
const quantity = 2;
const taxRate = 0.1;
const tax = price * quantity * taxRate
const totalPrice = price * quantity + tax;
```

Comment: yes, it should be 4 for the above numbers @user9988550

Comment: Total  values need to be greater than price * quantity??

Comment: OP was looking for price with tax.

Comment: 4 is the tax. You can then add it like this total_value = price*quantity + tax which equals 24, just as @fragezeichen states in his answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var price = 20;
var tax = 0.1;
var qty = 2;
//amount includes the tax
var amountWithTax = (qty * price) / (1 - 0.1);
console.log(amountWithTax);
//amount you get after you pay the tax
var amountAfterDeductTax = amountWithTax - (amountWithTax * tax) ;
console.log(amountAfterDeductTax)
```